# Opaque overlay on a long jQuery select menu popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, popup, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have a long list with a jQuery Mobile select menu widget which opens as a popup. The popup opens with a solid white background by default (and also if I explicitly set `data-overlay-theme=a` in the `<select>` tag), and if I change this attribute to `data-overlay-theme=b` then it opens with a solid black background. Elsewhere in my site I use jQuery popup widgets with `data-overlay-theme=b` and the background is an opaque black (maybe 50%).

Is there a way I can get the background of the select menu widget popup to have the same background as the popup widget?

[Here's a JSFiddle with a few demos](https://jsfiddle.net/fwx1vvz8/).

Comment: When the list gets long, jQM automatically switches from using a popup to a dialog which is essentially an indented page. So it is not an overlay anymore.

Comment: But it creates the white background, so surely there must be a way for me to apply opacity to it?

Comment: You can change the opacity: https://jsfiddle.net/fwx1vvz8/2/ but there is nothing under the overlay as a dialog replaces the current page unlike a popup which sits on top of it...